# Golang following container logs undeclared name Log

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, testing, testcontainers

I'm trying to build a container with testcontainers and output the logs to stdout.

I have followed their documentation (https://golang.testcontainers.org/features/follow_logs/) but when writing the `Accept` function, I get an error:

```
func (g *TestLogConsumer) Accept(l Log) {
    g.Msgs = append(g.Msgs, string(l.Content))
}
```

The problem is that I didn't import a certain package, so I can't use "Log".

I get the following error:

`undeclared name: Log`

**The question is**, which package should I import. How can I make vscode import these packages automatically for me ? I have installed the `go` extension, but it doesn't import anything automatically.

Comment: Regarding the non-automatic imports. Have you installed the Go tools required by the Go extension for VSCode? If not you can do that by opening the command pallet in VSCode and running the 'Go: Install/Update Tools' command. Select all tools to install/update them all.

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden Hello, yes I have installed the go tools required by the go extension

Answer (score 0):

The type you need is `testcontainers.Log`